# What do I need to get so I can upgrade my Thinkpad x61 Tablet hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, thinkpad, tablet

My Thinkpad X61 Tablet is running out of space, and I would like to give it a bigger drive.

I would like to clone the old drive to a bigger new drive. What do I need to get to accomplish this? The fewer things to get, the better, of course. The easier, the better.

My system: 
Thinkpad X61 Tablet. 
XP w/ the latest SP. I am OK with XP, and don't want to reinstall it. 
No optical drive. 
USB 2.0 connectors (Bootable, I think).

Things I have: 
USB 2.0 external drive housing. 
USB flash stick (2GB).

Answer (score 1):

get the right sort of hard drive - i do believe the x61 is new enough to use SATA. get a SATA-USB drive enclosure.

You can use  [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (which [you can load onto a thumbdrive](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php#make) very easily) to make a copy of the internal drive to the new one, in the caddy. switch drives, test, and if it works you're good

Since its the same system, you should probably not need sysprep, and you will not need to reactivate.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do is to get any larger compatible hard drive, then using a machine that has room for two drives, load [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net), you can copy and paste the partition to the new drive and then extend it to use the free space.

You may be able to get away without any problems, but just in case, I would personally do a `sysprep /genralize` just in case, so you do not have to reinstall Windows. [Read this question for more information.](https://superuser.com/questions/54300/booting-a-windows-7-installation-on-different-hardware/55215#55215)