# Fix BSOD error 0x7B without reinstallation

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bsod

I recently upgraded my machine from a z87 platform to an X99 platform (specifically the Asus x99 Deluxe + 5930k), and when I went to transfer my old SSD containing Windows 7 Pro x64 to the new build, (no surprise) it blue-screened on me with a 0x0000007B. However, unlike the other persistent BSODs I've received in the past, this one's truly stumped me. It seems that I am unable to boot Windows from the SSD in the new x99 build, but when I remove the SSD and place it *back* into the old build, it boots just fine...

Things I've currently tried (may not be a complete list)

- Toggled BIOS storage mode from AHCI -> IDE and back
- Removed all non-Microsoft filter drivers from SYSTEM registry hive
- Installed the storage/chipset drivers for my new machine on the OS
- Ran sysprep in an attempt to force driver rediscovery
- Ran a VBS script called Fix_HDC in order to fix HDD controller registry entries
- Rebuilt the Boot Configuration Data table
- Rebuilt the MBR
- Toggled BIOS INT 19 trap delay timings
- Ran `chkdisk` and `sfc`
- Attempted system restore from the recovery medium
- Other desperate miscellaneous fixes

Since it always seems to work just fine whenever I place it back in my old machine I'm extremely hesitant to think that it's an SSD or Virus problem... I would *really* prefer not to reinstall, but rather find a solution that keeps my full copy of Win7 intact.

To make matters worse, boot logging doesn't seem to work at all either.

Any ideas?

Here's the BSOD:
[image]

Comment: Check CSM (compatibility support module) in your motherboard setup. Try to enable it. It may be UEFI/MBR issue. Check "Secure Boot" as well. Make sure you have "Other OS", not "UEFI" there.

Comment: @user996142 I just checked and CSM *is* enabled, and "OS Type" Is set to "Other OS (Non-UEFI)", the same as my old BIOS settings...

Comment: On new system , disk may have different number (not the one written in bcd). hence boot manager does not see it. Have you tried to boot from CD to recovery mode and call ``bootrec /RebuildBcd`` ? It should rebuild bcd, and may help. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

Comment: @user996142 Tried that too and it still doesn't boot correctly...

Comment: Try to do bare metal image backup  on old hardware and restore in new. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3W1edVI5d4 . Do you have external HDD large enough to keep backup image?

Comment: [Possible answer here, see Williams answer](http://superuser.com/questions/54300/booting-a-windows-7-installation-on-different-hardware)

Comment: @Moab I already tried the accepted answer there and it still didn't boot correctly...

Comment: Sometimes actual BSOD picture can be useful.

Comment: @ilkhd Here's a picture of the BSOD (A screen-capture device wasn't available, sorry) -- https://i.imgur.com/H8JBZiE.jpg

Comment: check this Microsoft blog post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/08/05/troubleshooting-a-stop-0x7b-in-windows.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Read the article and just finished removing all non-Microsoft filter drivers from my storage device driver registry entries. Still not booting...

Comment: Uninstall all IDE controllers and storage controllers and disk drives, shut down computer, move ssd to new computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing a device driver, I would guess the one for the motherboard.

Try to repair Windows as described in [How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).
This mode of soft installation will  scan your Windows 7 computer for a startup problem and try to fix it so your computer can start correctly, especially in your case
fixing missing or damaged system and driver files.

If this doesn't work, get the driver from the ASUS website and add it in during the above installation process.

Comment: I've already installed both the chipset and storage drivers from ASUS' website... Sadly this did not fix it either.

Comment: Did you try a Repair installation?

Comment: Yes, I tried this on the old, working computer but when I went to transfer it into the new computer it still didn't boot...

Comment: You have to try it on the new computer, since it has to detect the right hardware.

Comment: How would I go about running a repair installation that preserves my data when I am unable to boot Windows 7 on the new machine to launch the executable? The bootable repair disc works, but IIRC if you do a repair from there it doesn't preserve your data/registry.

Comment: The procedure from the link above shows how to do a repair install that preserves almost everything. It would be safer of course to take a backup image on the old computer, just in case. A product I recommend is AOMEI Backupper.

Comment: "A) While in Windows 7 SP1, insert your retail Windows 7 SP1 installation DVD into the DVD drive, or connect your Windows 7 with SP1 installation USB thumb drive, and click on the Run setup.exe option in AutoPlay." -- After reading the article it still seems that I need to be booted into Windows 7 to preserve my data during a repair. Should I do this on my working computer, then? Something seems rather roundabout about this...

Comment: Sorry, wrong link for your case. Try Startup Repair as described in [this link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html). I also fixed my answer.

Comment: Well, this is new, I re-ran startup repair from the install DVD and it gave me this:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11354561/

Comment: Some extra details that might help from the startup repair logs are here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11354740/

Comment: Disconnect all possible devices before doing Starup repair. Check your BIOS settings for the disk : for example AHCI or IDE. See [this article](http://www.7tutorials.com/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records) for fixing via boot to command-line - please report on results. You could also try specialized products: [Paragon Rescue Kit Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/requirements.html) and [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/).

Comment: After attempting numerous repair installations a talk with an ex-Microsoft sysadmin and a computer repair technician both told me that it was both "improbable to work without reinstallation" and "not economically feasible" to attempt to get it to boot in the new machine. In light of this I have decided to back off my Windows data onto another HDD and install both Debian and Slackware on the SSD for the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 7, I've never had a problem inserting a drive into another computer. Even from desktop to laptop and vice-versa has worked numerous times.

I really want you to try installing a fresh copy of anything (preferably vista or 7) to check if there might be other hardware problems. If if fails to boot a fresh install on a clean disk, there are obviously other issues at hand.

Please also try booting with only 1 memory stick inserted into the mobo. Insert it in the first slot in the first channel or as described in the manual. I have built too many x79 and x99 machines to skip this step. The mobos are very fragile in my experience.

Make sure the SATA-mode is the same as in the old machine (probably AHCI).

and finally; did you make sure to uninstall Intel Rapid Storage Manager and all other Intel storage-stuff and Intel Matrix and such on the old computer? If the storage chips are very different, and the wrong drivers are loaded pre-winload, the 0x7b BS will definitely show up. 
Don't install any new storage drivers, just remove all storage-related drivers and clean the registry for on the old computer and shut down (don't restart). Move your hdd to the new machine and "complete the reboot" there (turn it on).

Comment: Perhaps I have seen to many bad question in a short amount of time.  This answer just seems to list a bunch of stuff that might solve the problem, most of these things, and on top of that are clearly things the author already tried.  This is more then a bad memory module problem.